# Is there a way to open two tabs for the same file in IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Sometimes I need to look at one piece of code already written and write another piece in the same file. When the code is too long, for beauty or other reasons, I have to write for a while and then slide to the piece of code I want to see, and then slide it back to write again. Is there any good way to avoid this trouble?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use a mouse to do it! Remember everything in IDEA is configurable so my keyboard shortcuts may not work for you though you can configure them in the [keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html).

There are two ways which you can open multiple files in IDEA:

The first method would be to split the editor:

1. [search by action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html#search_actions) `cmd shift A` on mac
2. type `split` and choose how you'd like to split [image]

The second method would be to open the file in a new flowable window:

1. Select on a file in the [project window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html#show-filesize-timestamp)
2. Use shortcut `shift f4` or [search by action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html#search_actions) `cmd shift A` on mac
3. Type `open source in new window` and hit enter
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

right click into tab name, and select split vertically or horizontally[image]

if you are using git. then find "local changes". it will compare your current changes with the origin
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-changes-information.html#comparing_local_changes

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio I see "Split Vertically/Horizontally" options when I right-click on the tab name which do exactly what you want. Since AS is derived from IDEA the functionality might be there too.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JetBrains IDEA, the form can be split vertically by right-clicking
If you use Eclipse, you can ctrl + shift + [